# SP2010: Retrieve web app url dynamically for request coming

Tags: development

I've created a web application on my sharepoint farm:  sharepoint.local
Name:  https://app.sharepoint.local

Outside of my farm the site is available through an UAG server on:
https://app.publicurl.com

(UAG/AAM pointing to the internal url)

In my code behind I use the current url to specify my web app url and execute some code.
I was wondring how I could dynamically retrieve my web app url if users are using the public url: https://app.publicurl.com

Are there out of the box functions for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this.Page.Request.Url, unless I'm missing something.